# java in terminal not completing

Tags: java, terminal, xfce

I have a java HelloWorld equivalent:

```
public class HelloWorld 
{
        public static void main (String[] args)
        {
                System.out.println("Hello World!");
        }

}
```

I compile just fine, and execute from the command line in a xfce terminal on Ubuntu 12.04.

```
java -cp . HelloWorld
```

Nothing happens, as though something has hung. I hit a key and "Hello World!" is displayed

```
java -vervose -cp . HelloWorld
```

This displays all the verbose stuff and then "Hello World!" and then terminates, no key press required.

I opened a new terminal, repeat the experiment, with the original invocation. No key press required, seeming to indicate that something was wrong with the original terminal instance. I'm really curious to know what. Other command line programs are behaving just fine.

Answer (score 3):

Did you type `\` in the end of the first command by mistake? Happens to me all the time.

This indicates to the terminal that your commands spans multiple lines (much like in source code), and so it waits for you to finish the 2nd line. Your pressing enter again would finish that line..

Comment: Nope, that's not it. I still have the terminal instance open and it's still behaving this way.

Answer (score 0):

Just to confirm (and reassure you) that I just ran your exact code on Ubuntu 12.04 and it worked as expected, without any delay. 
I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 with Gnome desktop (I don't have Xfce)

The first question that comes to mind is if other Java programs behave in the same way.

Comment: He was able to confirm himself with another terminal, though good suggestion to try other java programs..

Comment: Another separate java program (which was as simple as Hello World) was the first program where I spotted this, and so I quickly knocked up the Hello World instance to check.